# Put emblem on folder icon if it contains particular file/subdirectory

Tags: scripts, icons, directory, git

How can I create a script and system rule for all directories, that will apply emblem onto every directory's icon if the folder contains `.git` direct subfolder?
I have already included github emblem icon to my emblems [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmSqJ.png)

The output effect should be as so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Intorduction

<sub>NOTE: this is a new and updated version of the script, for old version see the edit history of this answer</sub>

The script presented below allows to either set a github repository icon or emblem (but not both), as well as reset that metadata back to default. Usage is very simple, as explained by the `-h` option:

```
$ ./set_folder_icon.py -h                                                                   
usage: set_folder_icon.py [-h] [-i ICON] [-e EMBLEM] [-r ROOT] [-u]

Finds and sets github repository icons.Choose either --icon or --emblem.
Without either the script exists with 0 exit status.For --icons, use absolute
or relative path.For --emblem use single string of text.Emblem pathnames are
in the format emblem-name.extension.The script then can becalled with -e
<name>.Use ~/.local/share/icons folder for custom emblems (if it does not
exist - create it. Store filenames in specified format

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i ICON, --icon ICON  path to image to set
  -e EMBLEM, --emblem EMBLEM
                        single-string emblem name
  -r ROOT, --root ROOT  where search starts,default - current working
                        directory
  -u, --unset           unset both emblem and icon. Cannot be used with -e or
                        -i options
```

So if we wanted to recursively search home folder  for all `github` repositories and set their emblem, we'd do `set_folder_icon.py -e myemblemname -r $HOME` or just `cd; set_folder_icon.py -e myemblemname`

For best performance, please create `~/bin` directory and store the script there as `set_folder_icon.py`. If you want to use it immediately, run `source ~/.bashrc`. If you're using a different shell, ensure that your `~/bin` is added to `$PATH` variable.

**NOTE**: The script can take any arbitrary file with `--icon` option, but `--emblem` requires you to have a specific file to be stored in `~/.local/share/icons` with filename something like `emblem-github`. See the **The script in action** section for an example

#### The script in action

I happen to keep all my github repositories under `~/GIT` folder. In the screenshots below you can see how all github repositores get their emblem set to the custom one.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

#### Script

The script is also available on my [personal GitHub repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep) , where it is more likely to get newer changes and fixes.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Author: Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
Date: 7/12/2017
Purpose: Script to find github repository folders
         and set their icons for Ubuntu.
Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/935003/295286
"""
import argparse
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import urllib.parse


def puke(message, status_code):
    """ Print to stderr and exit with given code """
    sys.stderr.write('>>> OOOPS. Something is wrong:\n')
    sys.stderr.write(message + '\n')
    sys.exit(status_code)


def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ Reusable function for running external commands """
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        puke('Called command failed with ' + str(cpe.returncode) +
             ' exit status\n' + repr(cpe), 4)
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout


def set_icon(directory, icon_type, image):
    """ Wrapper function that specifies command and calls run_cmd()"""
    key = 'metadata::' + icon_type
    meta = {'metadata::custom-icon': 'string',
            'metadata::emblems': 'stringv'}

    # Because custom-icons and emblems type are mutually
    # exclusive, we need to unset custom-icon to enable emblems
    if icon_type == 'emblems':
        cmd = ['gvfs-set-attribute', '-t', 'unset',
               directory, 'metadata::custom-icon']
        run_cmd(cmd)

    cmd = ['gvfs-set-attribute', '-t', meta[key],
           directory, key, image]
    return run_cmd(cmd)


def unset_all(directory):
    for key in ['metadata::custom-icon', 'metadata::emblems']:
        run_cmd(['gvfs-set-attribute', '-t', 'unset', directory, key])


def find_directories(tree_root):
    """ Does the job of recursive traversal of given directory tree,
        starting at the specified tree root directory. If condition for
        given subdirectory is met, calls set_icon() function"""
    for current_dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(tree_root):
        # This check can be adapted to other cases
        if '.git' in subdirs:
            print('Found', current_dir)
            yield current_dir


def parse_args():
    """ Parses command-line arguments """

    text = ['Finds and sets github repository icons.',
            'Choose either --icon or --emblem. Without either'
            ' the script exists with 0 exit status.',
            'For --icons, use absolute or relative path.',
            'For --emblem use single string of text.',
            'Emblem pathnames are in the format',
            ' emblem-name.extension.', 'The script then can be',
            'called with -e <name>.Use ~/.local/share/icons folder',
            ' for custom emblems (if it does not ',
            'exist - create it. Store filenames in specified format']

    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="".join(text))
    arg_parser.add_argument('-i', '--icon', help='path to image to set',
                            type=str, required=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-e', '--emblem', help='single-string emblem name',
                            type=str, required=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-r', '--root', help='where search starts,' +
                            'default - current working directory',
                            default='.', type=str, required=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-u', '--unset', help='unset both emblem ' +
                            'and icon. Cannot be used with -e or -i options',
                            action='store_true', required=False)
    return arg_parser.parse_args()


def main():
    """ Script entry point """
    # Parse command-line arguments and check their correctness
    args = parse_args()
    status_code = {'icon_missing': 1, 'root_missing': 2,
                   'root_isnt_dir': 3, 'exclusion': 4,
                   'not_string': 5, 'conflict': 6}

    if args.unset and (args.icon or args.emblem):
        puke('Conflicting options', status_code['conflict'])
    if not args.unset:
        # both or none are given
        if not args.icon and not args.emblem:
            sys.exit(0)
        if args.icon and args.emblem:
            puke('Can only use either --icon or --emblem',
                 status_code['exclusion'])
        # Verify correctness of either one
        if args.icon and not os.path.exists(args.icon):
            puke('Icon pathname does not exist',
                 status_code['icon_missing'])
        if args.emblem:
            if '/' in args.emblem:
                puke('Emblem must be a single string of text,no paths',
                     status_code['not_string'])
            if not isinstance(args.emblem, str):
                puke('Given argument for emblem is not a string',
                     stats_code['not_string'])

        # Verify correctness of the path
        if not os.path.exists(args.root):
            puke('Root pathname does not exist',
                 status_code['root_missing'])
        if not os.path.isdir(args.root):
            puke('Root pathname is not a directory',
                 status_code['root_isnt_dir'])

    if args.unset:
        for directory in find_directories(args.root):
            print('Unsetting', directory)
            unset_all(directory)
        sys.exit(0)

    # Everything should be OK past this point

    if args.icon:
        meta_type = 'custom-icon'
        icon = 'file://' + urllib.parse.quote(os.path.abspath(args.icon))
    if args.emblem:
        meta_type = 'emblems'
        icon = args.emblem

    # Now do the actual traversal and icon-setting
    for directory in find_directories(args.root):
        set_icon(directory, meta_type, icon)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Automating the script

Of course, we can run the script manually each time (in fact I'd likely make a function that can combine `git clone` and running this script), although I would recommend that you make the script run each time you log into your GUI session. In order to do that, open the Startup Applications menu, and add the script ( using full path and full filenames is recommended ) as an entry.

[image]

And next time you log-in your icons will be set.

As for manual idea, you could run `git clone` and  the script one after the other with `&&` operator, or better yet make a function in `~/.bashrc` for that like so:

```
$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
$ typeset -f my_gitclone
my_gitclone () 
{ 
    git clone "$1" && ~/GIT/sergrep/set_folder_icon.py -e github
}
$ my_gitclone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep
Cloning into 'sergrep'...
remote: Counting objects: 387, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 387 (delta 10), reused 17 (delta 5), pack-reused 365
Receiving objects: 100% (387/387), 115.65 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (203/203), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Found ./sergrep
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks promising. There is just one thing i haven't specified - i want to keep folder icon as it was, just add emblem to it, so the output  would be like so [link](http://imgur.com/a/wV88v)

Comment: @mtx ah, I see what you mean there. Can you please add that image to your original post ? That'll make it a little clearer. I'll try to work on it, will see what I can do.

Comment: @mtx I've found a couple of things, but that'll require rewriting  the script to use `Gio` API, instead of `gvfs-set-attribute` shell command.  I'll probably post it tomorrow. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @mtx I've updated my answer. The script now does both, emblem and icon. See the new version

Comment: when i run `python set_folder_icon.py -h` (copied from github) the console says : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set_folder_icon.py", line 13, in <module>
    import urllib.parse
ImportError: No module named parse`

Comment: @mtx  That's because you're running  it with `python` command, which is `python-2.7` on Ubuntu by default. The code is written with  Python 3, so either use `python3 set_folder_icon.py -h`  make script executable with `chmod +x ./set_folder_icon.py` and run as `./set_folder_icon.py -h`

Comment: yes, I can confirm now it works like a charm :) thanks a million!

Comment: is it possible to distinguish between repository on github and bitbucket somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62234/discussion-between-mtx-and-sergiy-kolodyazhnyy).

Comment: in every .git folder we have config file with url where its either github or bitbucket keyword, perhaps this could distinguish git provider? then what remains is how to point to respective emblems in command line - i think accomplishing it would finalize this beautiful script :)