# How can I make a subfolder that looks and behaves like Documents/Music/etc?

Tags: nautilus, icons, home-directory, xdg-base-directory

The home folder starts with default folders (mostly XDG base directories) like `~/Documents` and `~/Music`. These are decorated as follows:

1. custom folder icon (not an emblem)
2. custom icon matches the style of the regular folder icon
3. Nautilus bookmark in a distinct section (separate from other bookmarks)
4. custom bookmark icon

I have created a non-XDG folder called `~/Work`. How can I decorate it with **all four features** listed above?

Comment: The way to make it behave like a standard XDG folder, would be to get it into the standard, and then the implementations of the standard updated. Or shorter, you can't. The most you can really do is assign the custom icon, after having created one yourself that matches the theme.

Comment: @dobey that does sound like a long way round :) - I'd like to also add a custom bookmark, I've updated question to emphasize all-or-nothing requirement (unless something is literally impossible)

Comment: Custom icon/emblem assignment is something that can be scripted. Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/935003/295286  While application is specific to that question, it can be adapted for your purposes.